# gstreamer pipeline to mix two audio source

Tags: audio, pipeline, gstreamer

I want to create a pipeline in gstreamer that will have two audio source and will mix the audios with some scaling factor and through the output data to alsasink. I have seen the example of "adder" but am not sure if adder can be used with multiple filesrc. 
I need your help in constructing this pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it can !

Here's an example launch line to get you going :

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///home/meh/Music/Fonky\ Family-\ L\'amour\ Du\ Risque-MGvSx-foo3E.wav ! adder name = m ! autoaudiosink uridecodebin uri=file:///home/meh/Music/kendrick.wav ! audioconvert ! m.
```

Have a nice day :)

Comment: can i add two pcm files using adder. As with this current pipeline is not playing the pcm file even though i have added the capabilities.

Comment: Hm you should open a new question, or come on the irc on freenode, in the #gstreamer channel :)

Comment: I am using appsink in the c code for this pipeline. Is there any other way to link adder with either appsink or filesink. As nothing is played if i use filesink/appsink.

Comment: Not sure I understand, if you want audio to be played and stored at the same time you need to use http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html